# “The bridge is over the road.”

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, sentence-choice

Is it grammatically correct to say sentences like these:

- The bridge is over the road.( Meaning: The bridge is above/on a higher level than the road)
- The painting is over the sofa. (Meaning: The painting is above/on a higher level than the sofa)
- The helicopter is over the helipad. (Meaning the helicopter id above/on a higher level than the helipad)
- The blanket is over Lisa. (Meaning: The blanket is on Lisa covering her body)

I know that we could use “over” this way and it would be grammatically correct:

- The bridge over the road is very shiny.
- The painting over the sofa is a beautiful one.
- The helicopter over the helipad is an army helicopter.
- The blanket over Lisa looks cozy.

**Context:** I think it would be wrong to use “over” in the “x is over y” structure like in the first four examples, but since I was not completely sure I had to ask you for your opinion. There is a song called “I’ll Be Over You” by Toto. The structure in the name of the song kind of bugs my ears. So I had to ask this question.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing grammatically wrong, but we would be more likely to use a verb other than *is.*

> The bridge passes over the road.
>
> The painting is hanging over the sofa.
>
> The helicopter is hovering over the helipad.
>
> I've put the blanket over Lisa.

The song appears to use *be over someone* in the sense 'have ceased to be in love with them' (like 'getting over' an illness).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. So is it okay if I say the first four sentences I gave, or can we hear native English speakers say them? If we can, is it in a specific context or can they generally be said?

Comment: As I told you, native speakers would usually use a different verb when making a statement, as in my examples. We might use _is_ in some contexts. "I can see the bridge over the canal. -  No, the bridge is over the _road_, not the canal." "The helicopter is over the helipad right now, so it should land in a minute or two."